# What does this shared_ptr snippet say?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

```
void del(void(*)()) {}
 
void fun() {}
 
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<void()> ee(fun, del);
    (*ee)();
}
```

This is a piece of code found on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), I am trying to understand shared_ptr uses and this is an example I came across. I tried running this and making some modifications to this like adding cout statements inside the function body but I am unable to understand what is exactly happening here.

Adding a bit more of context related to my doubt,

My doubts specifically include:

1. This shared_ptr ee gets initialised with a function so why does simply `std::shared_ptr<void()>ee(fun);` not work?
2. Why do we have 2 functions in the constructor of ee ( I am assuming shared_ptr implementation is a class)?
3. Why does del have to take in a function pointer as its argument? What is the significance of that here?

Comment: It is a shared pointer with custom deleter.  It means that when ee goes out of scope function 'del' will be called. This can be useful when you have data not managed by new/delete but for example by some OS calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Hi Karl, I understand how function pointers work but this question is related to more specific case of shared_ptr used with 2 functions.

Comment: Please post the cppreference link that you have questions. Your question is about context but not syntax.

Comment: Hi Louis, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr here is the link. I have also updated the post

Comment: I believe cppreference stated the context before the code snippet. "This is sometimes used to keep a dynamic library or a plugin loaded as long as any of its functions are referenced:". That's for a dynamic library/plugin where its pointer should be deleted by the plugin itself.

Comment: The "trick" is that the deleter `del` doesn't actually delete anything. That lets you have a shared_ptr to something that should not be deleted, like the function. It's a tool to have in the bottom of your toolbox, but not widely used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> template <class Y, class Deleter>
> std::shared_ptr(Y* ptr, Deleter d);
> ```

1. This `shared_ptr` ee gets initialised with a function so why does simply `std::shared_ptr<void()>ee(fun);` not work?

The point is to create a context in which `del` is called after `fun` no matter what else is happening in the function in which `ee` is declared. It protects against early returns and exceptions.

2. Why do we have 2 functions in the constructor of `ee` ( I am assuming `shared_ptr` implementation is a class)?

`fun` is there mearly to make the shared pointer think it is owning a resource so that it will call the *Deleter* function when `ee` goes out of scope.

3. Why does `del` have to take in a function pointer as its argument? What is the significance of that here?

That's because the `shared_ptr` will call the *Deleter* function with a pointer to the resource it's owning. Since it's a function pointer, it can't really `delete` it - but it's needed to fulfill the contract you make when creating a shared pointer to a function.

The dereferencing of `ee` and calling the result is for clarity. It could just as well have been `fun();`, but `(*ee)();` is supposed to make readers of the code see the tight connection between the `fun` call and the necessity to call `del` when the function returns. It's not a "true" context handler because it opens up for mistakes:

```cpp
{
    std::shared_ptr<void()> ee(fun, del);
    // here someone mistakenly adds an early return:
    if (argc == 123) return 1;
    (*ee)();  //  or  fun();
} // del may now be called even if `fun` was never called
```

A similar construct without using `shared_ptr` could look like this:

```cpp
void del() {}
void fun() {}

template <class Out>
struct call_context {
    template <class In, class O, class... Args>
    call_context(In&& in, O&& o) : f(std::forward<O>(o)) {
        std::invoke(std::forward<In>(in));
    }
    ~call_context() { f(); }
    Out f;
};
template <class In, class Out>
call_context(In&&, Out&&) -> call_context<Out>;
 
int main()
{
    // call fun and will call del later no matter how `main` is exited:
    call_context cc(fun, del);
}
```

---

Another example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// same call_context definition as above

void fun() {
    std::cout << "Fun called\n";
}

int main() {
    call_context cc(fun, [] { std::cout << "main exited\n"; });
    std::cout << "---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Fun called
---
main exited
```

Comment: Hi Ted, why does it not call fun? Why don't we write only del in the initialisation of ee?

Comment: @Charlie I updated the answer to answer that.

Comment: I guess function types shouldn't have been allowed with smart pointers. They carry the name pointer, but they're not actually owning memory. What's the catch with paying extra overhead for reference counting?

Comment: @Red.Wave Yes, in my opinion, it is a misuse of a `shared_ptr`. It doesn't provide a proper guard and doesn't make the intention very clear - and it adds unnecessary overhead as you mention.

Comment: Hey, sir, one day since last met. I am also confused why `std::shared_ptr<void()> ee(fun, del);` won't work, and I don't know if I missed something, I don't see the explanation about this part in your answer. Could you provide a detailed explanation about that?

Comment: Buy the way, I think you should introduce [Deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter) to the OP, so that he can understand what a deleter is, and why we need to pass it as the second parameter, and why it takes a pointer as its parameter.

Comment: @LiuYuan Good point. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Q&A 1

> This shared_ptr `ee` gets initialized with a function so why does simply `std::shared_ptr<void()>ee(fun);` not work?

That's because `std::shared_ptr` does not accept a resource of function type, for the type of resource must be able to be allocated with `new` and to be freed with `delete`. However, by providing a customised deleter, the compiler won't call `delete` on this pointer, which makes the code safe, and compilation will success.

## Q&A 2

> Why do we have 2 functions in the constructor of ee ( I am assuming shared_ptr implementation is a class)?

As A1 has discussed, the second parameter is a cumstomised deleter. The `std::shared_ptr` has a built-in counter, which counts how many pointers are using the same resource. When you initialized an object, the counter is `1`. After you copied this object, the counter will increase while the counter will decrease by 1 when leaving the scope.

When counter decrease to 0, this means there are no objects using this pointer, thus we can deallocate it. The program call `delete` on this pointer by default. If we provide a cumstomised deleter(item 5 in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)), the program will call this deleter when counter decrease to 0.

In your case, at the end of scope, a pointer to `void func()` will be passed to `del`.

## Q&A 3

> Why does del have to take in a function pointer as its argument? What is the significance of that here?

This is explained in A2, for it needs the pointer to delete it, thus we have to design its API like this. Maybe this [document](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter) can give a better explanation.